# Relationship between IRS and Competitive equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics, competitive-equilibrium

If there are increasing returns to scale in both sectors (in a 2x2x2x2) production and consumption economy, then a profit maximizing allocation most likely involves the economy producing only one type of good?

Answer (score 2):

"Most likely" is not a precise term.

Given the available information it is quite possible that an equilibrium does not exist. In that case we can't really tell what will happen.